# Solution not found for > send: spawn id exp6 not open while executing

Tags: cron, expect

I am using the expect script to set up vpn and this script is working fine normally when executing it manually but when setting up it with cron job, it throws following error:

```
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "$syspass\r""
```

I tried my best to solve it but can't find any solution.I tried many solutions related it in the questions asked at Stack Overflow but none of it solved my problem.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set username "*****"
set password "*****"
set syspass "******"

spawn sudo killall openvpn
expect ".*for"
send "$syspass\r"
interact
spawn ./hma-vpn.sh -p tcp "UK"  
expect ".*for"
send "$syspass\r"
expect "?sername:"
send "$username\r"
expect "?assword:"
send "$password\r"
expect ":~"
send "echo 'connected'\r"
interact
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be readable and provide your script.

Comment: I'm wondering why you've tagged this as `python`? There's no code at all in this question?

Comment: Also, you would need to show us your expect script if you want actual answers.

Comment: run your script with `expect -d` to show debugging output. It sounds like the spawned process is dying quickly.

Comment: **expect -d**  did not solve that issue